# MVC4 with EF sample code with Unit of work, generic repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Are there any MVC4 code samples that use entity framework, unit of work and a generic repository pattern that I could use as a template?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/316068/Restful-WCF-EF-POCO-UnitOfWork-Respository-MEF-1-o

Answer (score 1):

I used this 2 tutorials to do this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4
and

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: While they are useful tutorials, there's nothing about Unit of Work in there.